# Turn text inside Javascript array in to a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/492cy/

I want to make the span id=textRange in to a hyperlink. Since I have different texts(from the array) populating textRange, I want each Text ("a dude", "a man", "a human") to become different hyperlinks.
Thus the end result would be: clicking on "a dude" leads to website1.com, "a man" goes to website2.com, "a human" goes to website3.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
var delay = "3"; //how many seconds you wnat the delay to be
var count = '0';
var Texts = ["a dude", "a man", "a human"];
var Links = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.bing.com"];

function changeText() {
    document.getElementById('textRange').innerHTML = "<a href='" + Links[count] + "'>" + Texts[count] + "</a>";
    count++;
    if (count == Texts.length) {
        count = '0';
    }
    setTimeout("changeText()", delay * 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/492cy/4/

Comment: How would I make the links open in another tab (target="_blank")?

Comment: That's right. Just add `target='blank'` before `href` in the line where the link is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what link you're trying to use but this works and will get you going.
You can use whatever href's you want but this shows you how to update the href of an `<a>` element.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9b6Tc/)

```
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById('textRange').innerHTML=Texts[count];
    document.getElementById('textRange').href = "http://website" + count + '.com';
    count++;
    if (count == Texts.length) { count = '0'; }
    setTimeout(changeText, delay * 1000);
}
```

Comment: How would I make the links open in another tab (target="_blank")?

Comment: Yes, add that attribute to the `<a target="_blank">` element. It should open in a new tab, but ultimately, the browser decides that behavior.