# Adding hyperlink in Javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, hyperlink

I have an array of objects and within each object there is an answers section, but I need to hyperlink some certain words that should send the user to a website.

I have given an example below.

```
faq: [
  {
    answers: "The capital is London"   
  }
]
```

So in the example above if you could show me how I can hyperlink the word London within Javascript it would be very helpful.

Many thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894107/turn-text-inside-javascript-array-in-to-a-hyperlink[

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have tried using the anchor tag within the javascript and the nuxt-link tag

Comment: And why didn't that work?

Comment: I did it like this - answers: "The capital is "<a href='"http://www.google.com"'>"London"</a>" ",

Comment: what do you need exactly? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I just need to find a way to hyperlink a certain word within an array of objects in javascript. For example, if I have many objects within an array and I want to hyperlink the word 'London'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just surround the word with anchor tag . Like this and give url after //

```
<a href="//www.google.com">London</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You can put your link instead of https://www.google.com. This will create hyperlink for word 'London'

```
 <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var result = "The capital is" + "London".link("https://www.google.com");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
        }
        </script>
```