# Vue.js - how to output link from an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to output a hyperlink from an object. Is it possible to do so?

I currently have this in my store.js, would like to use this info to output

it in a modal on my website. I got it to display it, but the a href is outputting as text.

Checked this, but none of these solutions worked for me:
[Adding hyperlink in Javascript array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812940/adding-hyperlink-in-javascript-array-of-objects)

```
export default {
  photos: [
    {
      name: "fox1",
      image: "fox01.jpg",
      id: 1,
      header: "Photoshoot with Fox Apparel",
      description:
        "Photoshoot with " +
        '<a href="https://fox.jp/" target="_blank">Fox</a>' +
        ", a sustainably - driven e - retailer from Canada."
    }
]
}
```

Comment: did you try v-html
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: I think your best bet is to extract the link into a variable and then put that into an anchor tag in your template, vue reads your data as string it can't know it's html

Comment: Can't you just feed the property with the link into a <a> tag?

Comment: Thank you, tried v-html but that outputs everything within the object as text (such as [ { "name": "fox", "image": "fox01.jpg", "id": 1, "header": "Photoshoot with Fox Apparel"}].

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:
https://nexladder.com/vuejs-tutorial/vuejs-v-html-directive

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="app">
           <div v-html="content"></div>
         </div>
         <script>
         new Vue ({
              el: '#app',
        data: {
                content: '<h2>Hello World</h2>'
        }
                 })
       </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Be aware that this can open up your site to [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Don't use this if the content is coming from untrusted users.